# Files.notExists always false in network directory

Tags: java, networking, file-io

I'm trying to use the Files.notExists method to check if a folder not exists. It works fine with local resources in my computer (Windows) but when I point to shared resources it always return false. The situation is the following:

Checking the non existence of local resources:

```
String stringPath = "C:/existentFolder";
Path path = Paths.get(stringPath);
Files.notExists(path) // false
//OK, because the folder exists

String stringPath = "C:/nonExistentFolder";
Path path = Paths.get(stringPath);
Files.notExists(path) // true 
//OK, because the folder doesn't exists
```

Checking the non existence of shared resources:

```
String stringPath = "\\sharedResourceName\existentFolder";
Path path = Paths.get(stringPath);
Files.notExists(path) // false
//OK, because the folder exists

String stringPath = "\\sharedResourceName\nonExistentFolder";
Path path = Paths.get(stringPath);    
Files.notExists(path) // false
//Why here it evaluates to false if it is indeed a non existent folder??
```

Comment: The code in your question is not valid Java code. There is no method with the signature `Files.notExists(String)`, only `Files.notExists(Path path,               LinkOption... options)`.

Comment: @Robert Yes, sorry I miss some lines. Just edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation of Files.notExists()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#notExists(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) states:

> Returns:
>   true if the file does not exist; false if the file exists or its existence cannot be determined

<s>I assume that un-mapped network shares can not be accessed using the File/Files classes, therefore the result *cannot be determined* (hence false).</s>

The following code works as expected using Oracle Java 8:

```
    String s = "\\\\myserver\\sharename\\directory";
    Path p = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(s);
    System.out.println(Files.notExists(p, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS));
    System.out.println(!new File(s).exists());
```

If the path is correct it outputs two times `false` and if it exists `true`. 
Have you checked that the network share is accessible in the Windows explorer?

BTW: The used network resource name is wrong. In Java you have to escape the backslash, therefore the correct String in the code for accessing a network share (if it would work) would be `\\\\sharedResourceName\\existentFolder`.

Comment: Mapping only applies to drive letters. UNC paths are always usable.

Comment: This works as expected and solve my problem! Thank you for the code and the explanations